# How do i iterate through a python script output in php exec_shell?? and display it on browser?

Tags: php, python, exec

This is the the php script i have written inside a html page

```
<?php
    echo "print php";
    $cs='python script.py';
    exec($cs,$out,$status);
    foreach($out as $value){
    echo "<div><p style=\"color:red;\">$value</p></div>";
    }
    ?>
```

***Browser displays no output*** Where am i going wrong?
Could someone please guide me on how to iterate through the output array am fetching? My python script gives few lines of output which is much like a text file. Thanxxx in advance for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's invalid `for` syntax, you're needing a `foreach`

```
foreach ($out as $value){
```

Comment: Oh yeah thanks!! i changed it to foreach but not able to display the output on browser. can someone please help me with that?

Comment: That should work if you've got exec enabled and the path to the script is correct. Check the value of `$status` and ensure you've got robust error reporting enabled.

Comment: This is helpful for catching errors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php